# searching for well-known security principals when running as Local User

Tags: c#, active-directory

--

My question relates to searching for well-known security principals from a C# program running as a 
local user. I can’t seem to make it work.

---

Here is my code:

```
DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://cn=wellknown security principals,cn=configuration,dc=demoDomain,dc=loc", "domainUser", "HIDDEN");
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(root);

// Performing the search
SearchResultCollection results = searcher.FindAll();
```

IT works fine when running as a domain user but when running as a local user (and connecting to the domain using user a domainUser)
I get this COM exception when trying FindAll(): “The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted” -2147023541 (8007054B).

Comment: I assume the u/p mentioned above (domainUser with password HIDDEN) is a user in the target domain itself? Have you tried supplying the domain name as well?

Comment: Yes user is domain user.
I have tried this and even impersonating a domain user.
No cigar yet :-(

Comment: The way I usually approach this sort of thing is a network sniff to see what exactly is being sent over and what sort of response you're getting. Netmon and wireshark are the tools I commonly use. Maybe someone else knows of a common cause of this, but in the absence of that, I'd go down the network sniff path...

Comment: Is the computer in the domain? What if you use the FQDN in the LDAP path: DirectoryEntry root = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://demodomain.loc/cn=wellknown security principals,cn=configuration,dc=demoDomain,dc=loc", "domainUser", "HIDDEN"); I assume the client does not know where to look.